# Java SHA1withDSA to PHP, convertible?

Tags: java, php, cryptography, sha1, dsa

Any success in implementing SHA1withDSA signature with PHP? A failure reported [here](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/03/howto-using-sha1withrsa-signing-in-php.html).

```
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec prvSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(prvKeyBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
PrivateKey prvKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(prvSpec);
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA");
sig.initSign(prvKey);
sig.update(text);
byte[] result = sig.sign();
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  What does your (PHP) code look like?  What, exactly, is going wrong?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an API in PHP, so I have no PHP code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are after the PHP [OpenSSL](http://php.net/openssl) extension.

Specifically, load the private key with [`openssl_pkey_get_private()`](http://php.net/openssl_pkey_get_private) and create the signature with [`openssl_sign()`](http://php.net/openssl_sign), passing `OPENSSL_ALGO_DSS1` as `$signature_alg`.

Comment: I cannot verify at the moment that this works or not. I accept this, as it seems reasonable.

Thank you caf!